# How do I get the App Access Token via the Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to retrieve the app access token of my app in order to post notifications, but for some reason, it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
$AppParams = array(
    'client_id'     => 'myclientid',
    '&client_secret' => 'myclientsecret',
    '&grant_type'    =>'client_credentials'
    );
$AppToken = $facebook->api('oauth/access_token?', 'GET', $AppParams);
```

I also replaced the first part with the full oauth/accesstoken link, but then it returns me general information about oauth and their facebook page, which I do not want.
I did nearly the same thing in C# and there it works.

Comment: The problem is most likely the ampersand characters in the keys of your array.  You don't need them. The SDK handles the building of the url and appending the parameters.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't really have to request an application access token. You can simply assemble one yourself.

An application access token is formatted like this:

```
app_id|app_secret
```

That's the application's id, a pipe character `|` and the application secret.

Make sure that this app token is not accessible to your users! Only use and reference it on the serverside - never pass this to the client. For more info, check out the last few sentences in the relevant [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens).

Comment: it doesn't work "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"

Comment: Hi again @Assaf :P This method does indeed work - I just reverified it via Facebook's debugger tool. Perhaps there is another issue with your request. I suggest that you try this method out manually using the [debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). Just put there your `app_id|app_secret` and you should get some info on your application.

Comment: @AssafShomer Are you using one of the official Facebook SDK's or making these requests manually?

Comment: Thank you man. Works fine. Exactly what I was looking for. Good for public content queries, like public events without need a logged user in the App

Answer (score 8):

With version 5 of the SDK you can get the access token with the `accessToken()` method of a [`FacebookApp`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookApp/5.0.0) instance. If you have a [`Facebook`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0) instance (as you normally would) you can get it like this:

```
$fb->getApp()->getAccessToken()
```

When I want to use my own app's access token I'm instantiating the API like this. I don't know if there's a cleaner way.

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($fb->getApp()->getAccessToken());
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace -

```
'&client_secret' => 'client_secret'

'&grant_type' => 'grant_type'
```